# Adding Existing File. No Reference Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've added a .cs file from an existing project to my new project. The file exists in the new projects directory after adding it.

I've included HTTP.cs. When I do the following, I get HTTP Reference not found:

```
private HTTP http = new HTTP();
```

What else do I need to do to reference this .cs file?

Comment: Did you add the using directive corresponding to the HTTP namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the namespace of the `HTTP` via the `using` keyword, like this:

```
using NamespaceWhereHTTPClassLives;
```

OR

Fully qualify the type name like this:

```
private NamespaceWhereHTTPClassLives.HTTP http = new NamespaceWhereHTTPClassLives.HTTP();
```

Comment: @GrantWinney - yes, that is true; good point. Several options here for the OP.